# Can`t change the background color of selected of a Kendo UI Grid row

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a grid that i want to change the background-color like this:

```
.k-grid .k-state-selected  {
    background-color: #11DED7;
    color:blue;
}
```

But it doesn't work, is only applying the color:blue but the background-color isn't applying. Why could that be?

The background color is always white.

This is the HTML code of the grid:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.3.1028/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.3.1028/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.3.1028/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.3.1028/kendo.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2016.3.1028/kendo.dataviz.bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcApp4.Models.MarcaParecido>()
                                      .Name("GridMarcaPar")
                                      .Columns(columns =>
                                      {
                                          columns.Bound(e => e.DescMarca).Title("Marca").Width(70);
                                          columns.Bound(e => e.DescTitular).Title("Titular").Width(100);
                                      })
                                      .Sortable()
                                      .Pageable()
                                      .ColumnMenu()
                                      .Selectable()
                                      .Scrollable()
                                      .Filterable()
                                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
                                      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                      .Ajax()
                                      .Model(model =>
                                        {
                                            model.Id(p => p.CodMarca);
                                        })
                                      .PageSize(20)
                                      .Read(read => read.Action("MarcaParecido", "Busqueda"))
                                      )

            )
```

Comment: its hard to know the problem without some code ...try adding !important

Comment: It is working for me here with your style block(without !important): http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/UgEGI.  Either post your code, or edit mine to show your problem.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I edit now and i put the code of my grid.